# Echoing html code in php

Tags: php

I am trying to echo the following code in html but it deosn't seem to work.

```
echo '<input type="submit"  value="Click!" style="width:100px;" onclick="$('#loading').show();"/>'
```

Please help

Comment: You need to escape your quotes if you use them inside of an echo statement. Simply Google "*escape single quotes php*".

Comment: The syntax highlighter shows your error. You need to escape your quotes.

Comment: You need to learn basic PHP string syntax: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have overlapping of `'` quote inside the JavaScript. You need to escape the single quote like this:

```
echo '<input type="submit"  value="Click!" style="width:100px;" onclick="$(\'#loading\').show();"/>'
// Notice the backslashes?                                                 ^         ^
```